# Issue getting collapsible navbar to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The collapsible navbar I made the other day works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Edge. It does not work in Internet explorer.

The issue is that the links of the navbar are still visible after the navbar has been collapsed. So the body content overlays on top of the links of the navbar. All links are still clickable as well.

Here is my collapse javascript, nothing too special.

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "20em";
        $("#footer").show();
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("content").style.marginLeft = "0";
        $("#footer").hide();
    }

    function toggle() {
        var toggleButton = $("#toggleButton");

        if (toggleButton.attr('name') === 'open') {
            closeNav();
            toggleButton.attr('name','close');
        } else {
            openNav();
            toggleButton.attr('name','open');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by showing and hiding the div containing the links.

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "20em";
        $("#footer").show();
        $("#links").show();
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("content").style.marginLeft = "0";
        $("#footer").hide();
        $("#links").hide();
    }

    function toggle() {
        var toggleButton = $("#toggleButton");

        if (toggleButton.attr('name') === 'open') {
            closeNav();
            toggleButton.attr('name','close');
        } else {
            openNav();
            toggleButton.attr('name','open');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.